# How many homotopy classes of curves joining two points are in a manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a manifold, $p,q$ ppoints in $M$. How many homotopy classes of curve joining $p$ and $q$ can I have in $M$? To be a litle more precise, the set of all homotopy class on $M$ is finite or infinite? In the last case, is numerable? The question is too general but my intention is to know which conditions must have a manifold to have certain number of homotopy class.

Answer (score 3):

The set of homotopy class from $p$ to $p$ is  with $\pi_1(M,p)$ if $M$ the fundamental group at $p$. Fix a path $c$ from $q$ to $p$ to an homotopy class $b:p$ to $q$ the concatenation $c.b$ defines an injective map to $\pi_1(M,p)$. If $M$ is compact $\pi_1(M,p)$ is finitely generated and a theorem of Gompf shows that every finitely generated group is the fundamental group of a $4$ dimensional manifold.

Comment: Would you suggest to me where to learn the global results as you stated? Thanks.

Comment: Start with the book of Bredon on algebraic topology

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.